# Calculate geometry not working in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: field-calculator, geometry, arcgis-pro

I have a set of points whose x and y coordinates I would like to add to the attribute table. The points are stored as a feature class in a geodatabase and I have ensured that they have the proper co-ordinate system (World Mercator).

I have tried using both `Calculate Geometry Attribute` and `Calculate Field` to add the data to the columns named X and Y but both just yield `<Null>` even though the tool runs successfully. For `Calculate field`, I am using the following Syntax:

```
X=!SHAPE.CENTROID.X!
Y=!SHAPE.CENTROID.Y!
```

Where am I going wrong?

I started testing at ArcGIS Pro 2.2.0 but have updated to 2.2.3 and the problem persists.

Comment: What is your syntax for `Calculate Geometry Attribute`?

Comment: @smiller: Target Field: 'X', Property: 'Point x-coordinate'. Target Field: 'Y', Property: 'Point y-coordinate'.

Comment: Is that *exactly* what you're entering in the field calculation dialog? If so you will need to get rid of X= and Y= because that's already assumed to be there. The return value from the calculation X= *whatever* is going to be Null *unless* there is an error, in which case it's an exception object which doesn't go well into a numeric field. However smiller is closer to correct, it should be !SHAPE!.centroid.X (remember python **is case sensitive**).

Comment: @MichaelStimson: No that is not exactly what I entered. I did not include X= and Y=. I included that in the question to make it explicit. Also, changing to `!SHAPE!.centroid.X` is not helping. I just tried.

Comment: Did you change to !SHAPE!.centroid.X and !SHAPE!.centroid.Y? It appears the replacement of the field name is not case sensitive but the property centroid is. Is your parser python or VB?

Comment: @MichaelStimson: Yes. I did. No change

Comment: See updated response and report back -- try just getting the !Shape!.X rather than !Shape!.centroid.X

Comment: Just out of interest the X and Y fields, are they set up as integer or string?

Comment: I just reran the model builder that was producing this shapefile a few more times and now it works!

Comment: I had a similar issue. I found that my field attribute was setup incorrectly (as 'TEXT' rather than a data-type that allows a numeric output, such as float). 
Whilst the tool ran, the fields remained as NULL. 
The error wasn't that helpful as it stated I didn't have enough character for the output - that that's what led me to check the data-type. 
The Error however said hat there wasn't 'space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partially, I believe the error is in the way the field is called. The exclamation marks (!) should surround the field name, but usually methods that come after the period should not be surrounded by exclamation marks. As commented by @MichaelStimson, this is case sensitive - so make sure centroid is lowercase.

Suggested modification (tested in ArcGIS Pro 2.1.2 and ArcMap 10.5):

```
!SHAPE!.centroid.x
```

And separately,

```
!SHAPE!.centroid.y
```

Comment: I had already tried `Add Geometry Attribute`. I also just tried your suggestion. But, no change. Still showing <NULL> even though the tool executes successfully.

Comment: CENTROID should be centroid, python is case sensitive and will have a cow saying something like *object has no property CENTROID*.

Comment: The new edits for `!SHAPE!.X` throws error "AttributeError: DescribeGeometry: Get attribute X does not exist"

Comment: Hmm, perhaps we could use the token !SHAPE@X! like what is described for SearchCursor

Comment: I was able to get !Shape!.centroid.x to work -- so I was wrong, need to use centroid even with points.

Comment: Still not working for me. I will port it over to ArcMap and see.

Comment: Accepting this answer as this is a valid solution to how to write the expression in `Field Calculator`. In my case, this was not working till I re-ran the model builder which produced the point feature class a few times. Now this along with `Calculate Geometry Attribute` both work. So, I guess there was something wrong in the way the model builder had created the feature class the first time.